# Prevent change of model date on keypress with ui.bootstrap.datepicker-popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [Angular-UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s datepicker-popup in my application.

If the user clicks and types in the text input, $scope.dt is updated after each keypress and the cursor position is reset to the end of the string, making keyboard-based entry or modification of the selected date very difficult.

Question: is there a straightforward way to modify the behaviour of the text input to prevent $scope.dt changing when the user types until the return key is pressed?

This is the standard sample code for using datepicker-popup:

```
<h4>Popup</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to an example Plnkr:

[Example Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vMMqaZezYixgaOioBMY6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is ngModelOptions. You can use the directive to tell the text field when to update the model value, delaying the actual binding.

For example: `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`

Documentation [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Or as an alternative you could create an on the fly model and only bind your $scope.dt inside a function within your controller if the enter key is pressed.

```
<input ng-model="onTheFlyModel" ng-keypress="checkForEnter($event, onTheFlyModel)"/>
```

(Now in your controller)

```
$scope.checkForEnter = function($event, onTheFlyModel){
    // Use $event object to check for enter.
    if(/*$event is enter key*/)
        $scope.dt = onTheFlyModel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about ng-model-options - that's very useful. However, it looks like the datepicker-popup directive must do its own keyboard event handling because adding this doesn't change anything in the Plnkr.

Your other suggestion may work, but I'd need to see how to do that without interfering with the model updates from the popup itself.

Comment: @StephenT It works. Out of laziness I used ng-blur instead of ng-keypress but this updated Plunker will demonstrate nonetheless (just make sure your input matches format *exactly* -> Ex: 01-July-2012 <-): http://plnkr.co/edit/jq8PRmWdjtpzmvLx665c?p=preview

Comment: many thanks for the example. It doesn't look like you're using ng-model-options. However, the example is close to what I'm trying to achieve, but not quite 100%: you still need to lose focus on the input to trigger the update from the popup. Ideally, I'd like to have $scope.dt updated immediately on change of selected date when using the popup, but only after pressing enter when editing via the keyboard.

Comment: @StephenT I was ***NOT*** using ngModelOptions, it was an example of the function solution. It was only a proof of concept example using the ng-blur event. Simply change my example to use ng-keypress and detect the enter key like I described in the post.

Comment: Sorry - I think we're talking at cross purposes: in my first comment, I was saying that ng-model-options doesn't seem to work in this case. I didn't see it in your plnkr, so I was wondering if you found the same? Were you able to get that solution to work in this situation? It certainly would be an elegant approach if it did.